# Two dimensional array every second two row c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I want to ask your help, I want to display a two dimensional array in c++, whose every second two rows are changing periodically between 0 and 1.
For example n = 5, m = 4 the program will write this:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still a beginner in C++. I tried it myself to see if I could do it.
The only thing you need to know is, when to assign 1 to your row and when to assign 0.

These are the the rows where you have to give every number the value 0:
**0,1**,2,3,**4,5**,6,7,**8,9**,10,11,**12,13**,14,15,**16,17**,18

again:

```
0,1,4,5,8,9,12,13,16,17
```

If you look at them like this, they don't make much sense. But if you divide them into two lists like this:

```
0,4,8,12,16
```

and

```
1,5,9,13,17
```

you can see that the first list consist of numbers, that are the result of n * 4, and the second list is the result of n * 4 + 1

So you just have to make an if-statement where the requirement is

```
(i%4 == 0 || i%4 == 1)
```

Here is my complete code. It's probably not the best solution:

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        const int n = 20, m = 4;
        int array[n][m];

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while ( i < n) 
        {
            if (j < 4)
            {
                if (i%4 == 0 || i%4 == 1)
                    array[i][j] = 0;
                else
                    array[i][j] = 1;

                cout << array[i][j] << ", ";
                j++;
            }
            else {
                j = 0;
                i++;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```